# Azure Devops deploy pipeline on my Resource was stuck

Tags: deployment, azure-devops

I have a project on `https://dev.azure.com`. And I want to setup deploy to my virtual machine from `master` branch automatically.
So, I read the [this manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops) and did the following things:

1. Create 'Production' environment
2. Create new Resource for this environment
3. Add new Virtual Machine as a Resource with `VMenv` name
4. Run registration script on my virtual machine => here my VM was connected to Azure Devops
5. Add tag `Production` to this resource
6. Add the following step to my pipeline:

```
    - deployment: deploy
      displayName: Deploy to production
      environment:
          name:  VMenv
          resourceType: VirtualMachine
          tags: Production
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
              - script: echo This is deployment on production
                displayName: Deploy project
```

7. And run this pipeline

And when I run this pipeline - it was stuck - [here you can find details](https://dev.azure.com/kolenkainc/azure_deploy/_build/results?buildId=1137&view=logs&j=d4aecca3-a437-5e55-8920-532a8eb17862)

Where I made mistake? How I can deploy on my virtual machine via azure devops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `deployment name` field has [known issues](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1044298/job-is-pending-1.html). If  `deployment:deploy` , the job will be stuck.

I could reproduce this issue too.

For a workaround:

You could change the `deployment field name`(Except deploy).

The deployment name could contain `A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore`.

For example:

```
jobs:  
- deployment: test
  displayName: Deploy to production
  environment:
    name:  VMenv
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
    tags: Production
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
          - script: echo This is deployment on production
            displayName: Deploy project
```

Then the pipeline job will run as expected.

**Additional information：**

In addition to using `Environment:VirtualMachine` for deployment, you can directly use [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install).

In this case, you could create the self-hosted agent on your Virtual Machine. Then you could directly use the self-hosted agent to deploy the resource to Virtual machine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps! Thank you a lot!